# Git best practices in everyday collaboration

Tags: git

Are there any published guidelines from the community on using Git in a medium-sized (15 developers) team, often with members across the country?

I've been reading about Git and watched a very good masterclass from O'Reilly but wondered if there were hard-learned lessons and resulting how-tos (and how-not-tos) on things like rebasing, when branching is a good idea (and when its not), etc.

Comment: Why don't you google it!

Comment: Was hoping to cut through the cruft and solicit SO experiences directly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess googling it is not that hard.
This article is terse and good, though I have difference in some points with the author

http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/

And here is a [branching model I found appealing](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)